# Mongodb Full text search Using PHP 5.6

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to use mongodb full text search for showing jobs list. I have done all the necessary steps to create the text indexes and enable the full text search feature on the database and everything is working fine except from the full text search using PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code in php for full text:

```
<?php 
$username = 'mongodbusername';
$password = 'changeMe';
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://myadmin1:myadmin123@localhost/dbname");
//$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost", array("username" => $username, "password" => $password,"db" => "jobma_integrations"));
$db = $m->integrations; // this is your dbname
$crawlingCollection = $db->crawled_jobs; // this is your collection name
$c = $crawlingCollection->find(
  ['$text' => ['$search' => "sales \"ardmore\""]], // this \"ardmore\" is used for exact match and sales will be match with any where 
  ['score'=> ['$meta'=>'textScore']]
)->sort(
  ['score'=> ['$meta'=>'textScore']]
);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(iterator_to_array($c));
?>
```

Comment: for ref https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-mongodb--cms-24835